# Как можно выровнять кнопки в этом меню в одну линию?

Tags: html, css

Знаю, что куча ошибок в css. Но я только учусь.

```css
* {
  transition: all .2s;
}

body {
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  padding-top: 0px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

.header {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="images/logotype.png" alt="Креативное агенство">
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="butta">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a id="lol" href="#">Зв'язатися</a>
  <a id="kek" href="#">Розповісти про проект<img src="images/arrow.png" alt="arrow" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px;" > </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Возможностей не мало...

Есть `display:inline-block;`, можно `flex-ми`, еще есть `grid-ы`

```css
* {
  transition: all .2s;
}

body {
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  padding-top: 0px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
ul{
/*
или так 
display:flex;*/
}
li {
/**/
display:inline-block;

  list-style: none;
}

.nav {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

.header {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="images/logotype.png" alt="Креативное агенство">
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="butta">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a id="lol" href="#">Зв'язатися</a>
  <a id="kek" href="#">Розповісти про проект<img src="images/arrow.png" alt="arrow" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 5px;" > </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

display: inline-block; в css попробуй прописать классу butta или nav

Answer (score 0):

сделать новый :

```
     <div style="width: 100%;
text-align: center;"  
    <button>
    ...
    </button>
    ..... </div>
```

в атрибуте style добавьте смещения и границы кнопок
Пример смотри тут - http://drupalace.ru/vyravnivanie-knopok-po-tsentru